# How does `angular-ui-router` determine where to insert a state view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I followed the example on [the github page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) of `angular-ui-router`. The example worked fine, but I am puzzled how `ui-router` determines where to insert the partial state views. On the [Dive Deeper](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) page, it says that

> When a state is activated, its templates are automatically inserted
>   into the `ui-view` of its parent state's template. If it's a top-level
>   state—which 'contacts' is because it has no parent state–then its
>   parent template is index.html.

However, in the example that I followed, I cannot find any information that indicates a parent-child relationship between states. For example, what is the parent of `state1.list`? Why?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The hierarchy is determined by the Dot Notation

From [the docs, Nested States & Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views):

> You can use **dot syntax** to infer your hierarchy to the $stateProvider. Below, contacts.list becomes a child of contacts.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {})
  .state('contacts.list', {});
```

So the parent of `state1.list` is `state1` because ui-router uses the dot notation to determine parent-child relations.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views):

> Methods for Nesting States
>
> States can be nested within each other. There are several ways of
>   nesting states:
>
> 1. Using 'dot notation'. For example .state('contacts.list', {}).
> 2. Use the
>      [ui-router.stateHelper](https://github.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper) to build states from a nested state tree.
>      Courtesy of @marklagendijk.
> 3. Using the parent property with the parent
>      name as string. For example: parent: 'contacts'
> 4. Using the parent
>      property with the parent object. For example parent: contacts (where
>      'contacts' is a stateObject)